# Converting vertical scroll to horizontal div position jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Been battling with this for a while. Seems simple enough but I seem to lack the logic required to get it to work.

I want to convert the vertical .scrollTop position to a horizontal bar that represents the users vertical position in the document.

I think my math is terrible; am ready to be shot down in flames.

```
var pos = $("#content").scrollTop();
var convert = (pos / 1024);

$(document).scroll(function() {
    $(".place").animate({
        left: '+=' + pos
    }, slow);
});​
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/broman/SzLNg/) of where I am so far. The 'place' div doesn't want to move.

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SzLNg/8/)?

Comment: Almost! Amazing. The only requirement is that the movement of .place is restricted to 0 - 1024px. The movement should be relative to the vertical scroll position, regardless of how tall the window (or #content) is... I think this is why I was trying to divide the height of #content by 1024...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by converting the scroll position into a percentage

```
 var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    d = $(document).height(),
    c = $(window).height();
  var percent =  scrollPercent = (s / (d-c))
```

then get your current position by using that percentage for the width of the .placebar

```
var newPos = percent*1024;

if(newPos > 984) { //check to stop limit
   newPos = 984;
}

$("#place").stop().animate({
    left: newPos +"px"
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SzLNg/19/)

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much, this approach makes complete sense and as always I just wish I could've thought of it myself. @AbstractChaos RULES